# SonarQube 6.7.x is taking 31 hrs to scan 600k lines of code using sonar scanner 3.4. However with sonar qube 5.6.x it use to take only 30 mins

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I observed there are multiple duplicate lines printed as below. Its not an issue with Machine performance as even after increasing CPU and RAM, there is no improvement in overall time for analysis

```
[INFO] 2308/3796 files analyzed, current file: <projectpath>\src\com\dhs\riskadj\imports\rapsreturn\util\ImportRAPSReturn.java
[INFO] 2308/3796 files analyzed, current file: <projectpath>\src\com\dhs\riskadj\imports\rapsreturn\util\ImportRAPSReturn.java
[INFO] 2308/3796 files analyzed, current file: <projectpath>\src\com\dhs\riskadj\imports\rapsreturn\util\ImportRAPSReturn.java
[INFO] 2308/3796 files analyzed, current file:     

Sonar configurations as below
# path to source directories (required)
sonar.sources=project/source, project/source
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.java.source=8
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.exclusions=**/*.js,**/*.css,**/*.xml,**/*.html,**/*.xsd
sonar.java.binaries=**/classes/**
```

Please suggest if any settings to be modified in SonarQube to improve performance of scan. I have seen duplication exclusion but I think its just to skip some classed based on patterns. We are upgrading to sonarqube 6.6 or above version as it has better issue tracking system (graph like when it was introduced under activity tab of sonarqube for tracking purpose)

```
I am using jenkins to run the scan post build. I tries sonar scanner versions from 2.4 till 3.4 but same results. If I change to previous sonarqube version i.e., 5.6 its faster in 30 mins
```

After enabling logs I can see below error some times

> org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker$MaximumStepsReachedException:
>   reached limit of 16000 steps for method updateSpecialStatusHistory#212
>   in class MemberActivityManager    at
>   org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.throwMaxSteps(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:281)

Comment: Is the analysis stuck always on the same file? Also, the versions you are using are quite old, can you try to use a more recent version like 7.5?

Comment: Hi Tibor No analysis doesnt stuck anywhere. I have tried 7.4 and 6.7 both and same result. I think 7.5 is released few days back but I dont think it will create huge difference in performance but still I will try with it. Thanks for response

Comment: What is important here is not the version of SonarQube, but the version of SonarJava. Maybe one rule is slow in your context. Try to disable all Java rules from your quality profile, just to verify. Also precise if you are using only SonarSource official analyzers, or also third party (Findbugs, PMD, ...).

Comment: Hi Julien we are using Java 8 for sonarqube and using sonar source official analyzers only. I need to try by disabling all profiles but it will be too difficult to find which rule is taking time as those are 300+

Comment: I am not sure why same file is printed logs several times.  Does anyone knows reason behind it?

Comment: the log prints every 10 seconds which file it is analyzing : this means that the analysis is choking on this file. You could try to exclude that file from the analysis to determine if it is the culprit. You could also try to deactivate some rules to determine by dichotomy which rules are causing trouble.

Comment: Its happening for almost all files so cannot exclude only 1 file

Comment: I created custom profile in sonarqube 7.5 and imported all rules from 5.6 version but still it takes same time. Surprisingly, even if I disable all rules in custom profile still it takes same time. No difference. Hence I think problem is somewhere else in newer versions and not related to any specific rule

Answer (score 0):

It turn out to be disk read/write issue. Performance of non-ssd drive was very slow on virtual machine box. Hence no improvements were seen after upgrading CPU and RAM.
Since its resource intensive task I recommend physical machines or virtual box with good read/write speed.
I chose physical machine and now it takes hardly 40 mins for same job. Thanks all for help!